# TreeView (MVVM ) : Update Text Box from selected Item of tree

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I just started learning WPFand MVVM.Here is what i want to do:

When use select any node from tree , Description of that node is displayed in text box.
Here is XMAL( which was working for combobox not for treeview)

```
      <Grid Margin="0,0,0,33" Name="grid1">
        <TreeView   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="24,47,0,6" 
            Name="treeView1" 
            Width="120"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.}">        

            </TreeView>
        <TextBox
            Margin="150,47,24,61" 
            Name="textBox1"
            Text="{Binding Path=CurrentItem.Description}"
                 />
    </Grid>
```

Comment: What is CurrentItem ? property in ViewModel.....

Comment: @ethicallogics as i said i copied snippet from some example of checkbox.  Description is a property.                               Text="{Binding Path=Description}"
But does not change when i select nodes.it remain same. So i want it to change when i select other node

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it this way

```
<TreeView   HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="treeView1"
        Margin="24,47,0,6" 
        Width="120"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.}"   >
        <TreeViewItem></TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
    <TextBox
        Margin="150,47,24,61" 
        Name="textBox1"
        Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Description, ElementName=treeview1}"
             />
```

TreeView do have readonly SelectedItem property .I hope this will help.